# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (5.0.0-rc5) ignoring public fields

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

First off, this worked fine in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.
So given this model & endpoint;

```
public class TestRequest
{
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public string test2;
}

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] TestRequest value)
{
}
```

Swagger only shows;

```
{
  "test1": "string"
}
```

as the example TestRequest value.

Is this behaviour intended now?
Is there anyway to change this via setup or filters?
I have a ton of imported services that only use fields. (generated by dotnet-svcutil, which is pretty common)

Comment: Your `test1` is a property.  Your `test2` is a field. Swashbuckle only shows properties

Comment: So Swashbuckle v4 showed fields and properties but v5 only shows properties? Is there a link about this new behaviour you can share?

Comment: I don't know. I read your question *"Swashbuckle (5.0.0-rc5) ignoring public properties without getter/setter"* and answered it by saying, "well one of those is a field and not a property". Swashbuckle is *very* configurable. It's possible that the defaults have changed. Go find the startup/config code and see if you can change things.

Comment: Well I spent a day trying to figure it out, how much longer until I ask the question here? I was hoping this issue would be splashed all over the place since aspnet core 3.1 requires you to use the Swashbuckle v5 RC. At this point I don't even know if it's a bug or intended.

Comment: My point is that your question should really be phrased in a way that points out that v4 (on .NET vN (for some N)) documented both public `fields` and public `properties`, but v5rc on .NET Core 3.1 only documents `properties`. Get the "getters and setters" out of there. Ask if there's something config that needs to be set

Comment: ok you're right about the fields vs properties, I modified the question - and have since found the answer.

Answer (score 4):

ok, taking @Flydog57 suggestion to figure it out myself, I found that the new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore is using the MS json.net over  Newtonsoft.

So reading over the git readme a tenth time at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

I found that there is a way to revert the json serializer back to Newtonsoft.
First (as of the 5.0.0-rc5 release) install this package;

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft -Version 5.0.0-rc5
```

Then in Start.ConfigureServices tell Swashbuckle to use by;

```
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

Now you'll find all those public "Fields" have reappeared in your swagger page.

Update: .Net 5+ has an "IncludeFields" option in JsonSerializerOptions class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-5.0

So easy peasy now.